# What does CR mean in version numbers?

Tags: versioning

Hibernate has CR postfix in their releases for the 4.0 version of hibernate, for example 4.0.0.CR7. What does the CR part mean? When would I use this kind of release numbering?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> It's actually Candidate Release.

**CR=candidate for release**

The use of the CR (Candidate Release) qualifier is for releases that we anticipate can be the GA release, but we need the community to help validate the release.  Again, there is an optional numeric qualifier that can be added if there is a need for multiple CR releases.  Finally, the use of the Final qualifier is for completed releases for the community.

Check the following links for more information and confirmation:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2449518
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProjectVersioning
http://antwerkz.com/javabot/javabot/home/3/%23hibernate/2/29/1/11/0/2011/

Comment: Interesting. I've only ever seen "release candidate" before, never "candidate release".

Comment: yes.. i have seen on wikipedia also. RC.. may  be java uses this term

Comment: @JohnBartholomew Tthe reason for "CR" instead of "RC" is because the qualifier part of the version can be compared using String.compareTo(anotherString). So the version with "CR" would be "lesser" than the one with "Final". Having it as "RC" would fail this condition. From the link shared in the answer - http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProjectVersioning

Comment: Maven reserves both "CR" as well as "RC" as special strings.  Just a redundancy, or might they have separate meanings? https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification